# Inheriting from a template class, using a type defined in the derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I'm trying to inherit from a template class, using a type defined in the derived class.
I have tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
class A : std::vector<A::B>
{
    enum B { foo, bar };
};
```

Is there an elegant way of doing this ?

Edit : I know that it works if B is defined earlier. But i'm looking for a solution that allows encapsulating the type B inside the A class.

Comment: What do you want to do? What is your *goal*? Without knowing it, its not possible to tell you "elegant way" of doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my view, the best (admittedly indirect) solution is to use composition rather than inheritance:

```
class A
{
    enum B { foo, bar };
    std::vector<B> bs;
};
```

If for some reason you need (or really want) to use private inheritance to embed the vector in your object, then the type will need to be defined before the class, at namespace scope, since types cannot be used before they are declared. If they are not indended to be accessed by users of the class, and you don't want to pollute the namespace containing your class, then you could put them inside a namespace to indicate that they are implementation details:

```
namespace details
{
    enum B { foo, bar };
}

class A : std::vector<details::B>
{
    typedef details::B B;               // if you don't want to write "details::B" everywhere
    static const B foo = details::foo;  // if you don't want to write "details::foo" everywhere
    // and so on.
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't forward declare an enum in C++03.  Just use normal composition by having a the vector as a member and forwarding by hand.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to define `enum B` before it's use to inherit.

Also, you're not inheriting from the Standard `vector`, are you?

Comment: I know, but I would like the type `B` to be inside the A class, not in global scope. And yes, in this example I meant `std::vector`, is that a problem ?

Comment: @otibom: Well, it has no virtual functions, including no virtual destructor, so it's kind of pointless to inherit from it instead of just making it a data member. Most people have a "details" namespace in which they throw junk that isn't part of the intended API where stuff like this goes.

Comment: Oh, yes, but this was just an example. Also, it's private inheritance here.

Comment: @DeadMG: "it's kind of pointless" - if the only thing you use inheritance for is dynamic polymorphism, then it's pointless. But then so is private inheritance.

Comment: @Steve: Private polymorphic inheritance certainly isn't pointless - it allows the class to give a reference to itself to another class that expects a particular interface, without exposing that interface to the world. Private implementation inheritance doesn't offer anything that private composition doesn't, apart from saving a few characters when using the inherited/composed object (as long as your class isn't a template), but introduces problems like the one in the question and, in my view, makes the relationship between the two classes slightly less clear.

Comment: @Mike: do you mean that the "other class" is a friend of the first class? If so, that's using private+friend for something that personally I'd either use public+documentation, or else I'd pass the other class a proxy that is a friend of the first class and implements the interface by calling private functions, so as to restrict the "leaky privates" strictly to the business of implementing this interface, not to the whole of whatever the other class does. I'm not too concerned by your lack of clarity what private inheritance means, as long as you aren't reviewing my code ;-)

Comment: @Steve: No friendship needed, and no leaky privates. My class is `class Thingy : private Interface`; the other class has a method `DoStuff(Interface&)`; I call it as `other.DoStuff(*this)`. The other class needs no knowledge of my class at all, and certainly no knowledge of its privates, and the rest of the world doesn't need to know I'm implementing that interface for that particular class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your answers, but I just found a (edit: bad) solution :

```
namespace
{
enum B_type { foo, bar };
}

class A : std::vector<B_type>
{
    typedef value_type B;
};
```

Comment: The anonymous namespace doesn't do anything useful since it pollutes the encapsulating namespace with B_type just the same as if the namespace were not there at all.  Anonymous namespaces are pointless in header files, FYI.

Comment: Worse than namespace pollution: this means that `class A` will contain a differently typed member in each compilation unit, breaking the "one definition rule". If you really insist on using inheritance rather than composition here, then put the extra type definition in a named namespace (`details` is a commonly used name for namespaces containing implementation details that, for one reason or another, can't be private class members).