# C++ Class inheriting from template class without knowing the type?

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance

I am designing a template class Policy which needs to be able to handle pointers to other classes.

```
template <class P>
class Policy
{
  private:   
    const P *state;
  public:
    Policy (P const* s) : state(s){};
};
```

This works fine.
Now I want to inherit from the above template class and create new subclasses:

```
class Greedy : public Policy<???>
{
  public:
    template <typename P> Greedy (P const* s) : Policy(s) {}:
};

class Explora : public Policy<???>
{ 
  public:
    template <typename P> Explora (P const* s) : Policy(s) {}:
};
```

Problem is that when defining those classes I do not know what type they will be using for the base template class. Is this even possible to do ?
I want the type obtained from the inherited class constructor (probably templated), and then pass it to the base class construtor.
Can I do that ? If yes, how ? typedefining enums ?
I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927648/inheriting-from-a-template-class-using-a-type-defined-in-the-derived-class) but it doesn't in my opinion really answer the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make them template classes:

```
template <typename P>
class Greedy : public Policy<P>
{
    // now you know
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I was under the impression that a template class could not inherit from a template class, or is it only if the base class has a virtual ?

Comment: @Alex: I template class is just a normal class, once you give it template arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do it (see GMan's answer for the correct parametrization of the derived type), but bear in mind that you will get **entirely independent** class hierarchies for every type `P`. You are not magically creating a super class that has an arbitrary number of member types.

Consider templates as a code generation tool. They do not create a "type-generic type", rather they create lots of parallel *instances* of concrete, static types at compile time following a generic pattern.

---

If you truly want one single common base type, perhaps you can make the type of `state` polymorphic:

```
class Policy // no template
{
  StateBase * state;
public:
  Policy(StateBase * s) : state(s) { }
};
```

Then all your derived classes can access the states' common interface.

Comment: So is this bad ? Will it bloat up the executable ?

Comment: It depends **entirely** on what you want to achieve. Templates and inheritance are sort of orthogonal concepts; templates are type-generic, work "in parallel" and don't see each other, while inheritance is type-fixed and "goes down". Use templates if you have a repeating pattern, and inheritance if you have common interfaces.

Comment: Well in this case I want a combination, of a baseclass which can work which will be generic (work with many types), yet be inherited from other classes. Is it bad practise to mix those two ?

Comment: @Alex: Get it working in the cleanest fashion possible, *then* worry about performance.