# Inheritance Issue - Expected class-name before '{' token

Tags: c++, inheritance, compiler-errors

So I'm getting this error that has something to do with the way my AVLTree class is inheriting my BTree class. So far as I can tell, the compiler is acting as though it can't find BTree.h (which is in the same directory) or otherwise just doesn't like the way I'm including it.

I've been looking around online, but most examples I see of this problem involve someone forgetting to include something, so I'm not sure what to do next.

Edit: I've also added the code sample for BTree.h

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

> g++ -g -w -Wall TreeTest.cpp BTree.h BinaryTree.h AVLTree.h -o
>   testTrees In file included from TreeTest.cpp:12:0: AVLTree.h:22:29:
>   error: expected class-name before '{' token TreeTest.cpp: In function

And here is the code:

```
#ifndef AVLTree_H
#define AVLTree_H

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "BTree.h"

using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::string;

template <class T>
class AVLTree : public BTree{
    public:
        struct TreeNode{
            TreeNode * leftChild, 
                 * rightChild;
            T key;
            vector<T> data;
            int size;
            int height;
            bool deleted;
        };

        //Standard tree functions
        AVLTree();
        virtual ~AVLTree();
        virtual bool isEmpty();
        virtual int getSize();
        virtual int getHeight();
        virtual int insert(T key, T data); //returns number of insert calls
        virtual int remove(T key);         //returns number of remove calls
        virtual int contains(T key);       //removes number of contains calls, or 0 if doesn't exist
        virtual std::vector<T> getData(T key);

        //Special functions
        virtual void displayAll();
        virtual double getAverageDepth(); 
        virtual int getTotalIPL();  //Retrieves internal path length from root

    private: 
        int size;
        TreeNode * root;

        int * contains(T key, TreeNode * node, int calls);
        int insert(T key, T data, TreeNode *& node, int calls);
        int remove(T key, TreeNode *& node, int calls);
        int getDepth(TreeNode*curr, int total);
        int getIPL(TreeNode * start, int level);
        void rotateLeft(TreeNode *& node);
        void doubleLeft(TreeNode *& node);
        void rotateRight(TreeNode *& node);
        void doubleRight(TreeNode *& node);
        int max(int a, int b);
        int getHeight( TreeNode * t );
        void display(TreeNode * node, string indent, bool last);
        TreeNode * makeNode(T key, T data);
        TreeNode * getNode(T key, TreeNode * node);
        void destroySubTree(TreeNode * start);
};
```

And here is BTree.h:

```
#ifndef bTree_H
#define bTree_H

#include <vector>

template <class T>
class BTree{
    public:
        struct TreeNode{
            TreeNode * leftChild, 
                 * rightChild;
            T key;
            std::vector<T> data;
            int size;
        };

        //Standard tree functions
        virtual ~BTree();
        virtual bool isEmpty() = 0;
        virtual int getSize() = 0;
        virtual int getHeight() = 0;
        virtual int insert(T key, T data) = 0; //returns number of insert calls
        virtual int remove(T key) = 0;         //returns number of remove calls
        virtual int contains(T key) = 0;        
        virtual std::vector<T> getData(T key) = 0;

        //Special functions
        virtual void displayAll() = 0;
        virtual double getAverageDepth() = 0; 
        virtual int getTotalIPL() = 0;  //Retrieves internal path length from root

    private: 
        int size;
        TreeNode * root;

};

template <class T> 
BTree<T>::~BTree<T>(){}

#endif
```

Comment: So, which line is it pointing at?

Comment: AVLTree.h:22:29: error: expected class-name before '{' token. It's line 22, where I wrote "class AVLTree : public BTree{"

Comment: Could you show the contents of Btree.h?

Comment: I went ahead and added BTree.h above.

Comment: I think you need to inherit from Btree<T>, since Btree is a class template

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671446/c-class-inheriting-from-template-class-without-knowing-the-type

Comment: You were right! Submit it as an answer so I can give you proper credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since BTree is a class template, you cannot inherit from it directly, but have to specify an instantiation of it. That is you have to provide the template arguments, which in your case should be the same type AVLTree was instantiated with.

```
template <class T>
class AVLTree:public BTree<T>
```